Pine Script 5 for TradingView: Trying to get the Hundreds or Thousands value to draw a line
I'm trying to draw a horizontal line at certain intervals on a chart. If the price is less than 10000, I want a line every $12.50. If greater, I want a line every $125. I want the lines to start the hundreds or thousands mark respectfully. In the code below, it will plot OK on one chart for a symbol, but on a different chart with the same symbol it plots at a totally different starting price. Here's the code:
//@version=5
indicator("Inflection Levels", overlay=true)

line_color = input.color(color.aqua,title = "Line Color")

// Starting point and interval
var base_divider = 100    
var interval_mult = 1

if close >= 10000
    base_divider := 1000
    interval_mult := 10

priceBase = (math.ceil(close/base_divider) * base_divider)
var float start_price_level = priceBase
var float interval = 12.5 * interval_mult

var int loop_count = 8
var float line_price = 0.0

// Draw cyan lines at each interval
for i = 0 to loop_count - 1
    line_price := start_price_level + (i * interval)
    line.new(x1 = bar_index - 100, y1 = line_price, x2 = bar_index, y2 = line_price, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = line_color, style = line.style_solid)

Here's a picture of what's happening:


It's almost like it's not using the last close price to start the lines. If I code in a constant number it works. Any suggestions?
